VSC IntelliSense suspends every time I save a file
I'm using Visual Studio Code 1.93.0 in Ubuntu 24.04 with the following extensions:

C/C++ v1.22.2
ESP-IDF v1.8.1
PlatformIO IDE v3.3.3

and some others that should not matter for the specific question.
When I open a project that uses PlatformIO IDE and C++ the IntelliSense works fine: syntax highlight, auto-completion, navigation (declarations/implementations), refactoring, etc...
Since a few days, when I open a project that uses ESP-IDF and C, it takes several minutes before all the above features are available. And every time I save a file, they stop to work for another few minutes.
I tried to:

C/C++ Reset IntelliSense database
C/C++ Rescan Workspace
check for VSC updates
check for extensions updates

But nothing fixed the issue.
I also noticed that every time I save a file (and until the features are available again) the process cpptools-srv is quite active, with about 4% CPU and minimal RAM usage. Hence I don't think it's the same issue described here.
Here is my settings.json:
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Linux",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**",
                "${config:idf.espIdfPath}/components/**"                
            ],
            "defines": [],
            "compilerPath": "${config:idf.toolsPath}/tools/xtensa-esp-elf/esp-13.2.0_20240530/xtensa-esp-elf/bin/xtensa-esp32s3-elf-gcc",
            "cStandard": "c17",
            "cppStandard": "gnu++17",
            "intelliSenseMode": "linux-gcc-x64"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}

and my c_cpp_properties.json:
{
    "idf.adapterTargetName": "esp32s3",
    "idf.flashType": "UART",
    "idf.port": "/dev/ttyACM0",
    "files.associations": {
        "usb_serial_jtag_vfs.h": "c",
        "uart_vfs.h": "c",
        "common.h": "c",
        "i2c_master.h": "c",
        "modbus_params.h": "c",
        "esp_mac.h": "c",
        "freertos.h": "c",
        "datetime.h": "c",
        "time.h": "c",
        "time_t.h": "c",
        "condition_variable": "c",
        "ctime": "c",
        "mutex": "c",
        "shared_mutex": "c",
        "spi_master.h": "c",
        "task_wifi.h": "c"
    }
}

UPDATE
Following the hint of user starball I ran the extension bisect and I found out the culprit is ms-vscode.cpptools. Of course disabling the extension is not the solution! It's odd that with other projects it works fine.
How to find out the root cause of the issue?

do you have format on save enabled?

@starball, no, it is not enabled

I don't know if the problem is solved, but I'll give you the solution using my case as an example.
In my case, recent version of C/C++ Extension was the cause of the problem. There are some problems related to symbolic link of code files. In other words, the extension doesn't recognize some files in Intellisense.
I modified .json several times, updated VS Code, re-installed extensions, and so on. But nothing changed like your case.
So long introduction, and here is solution:
"Downgrade your C/C++ extension to 1.19.9 version"

Go to C/C++ extension
Click the drop-down arrow beside the "Uninstall" button
Click "Install Another Version"
Choose 1.19.9 version
Done!

Then you can see that C/C++ Intellisense is working as usual.
